# Generating Content-MD5 for AWS S3 REST in Haxe

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, haxe

I'm trying to add a Content-MD5 header to my REST calls to AWS S3 in Haxe (compiling to PHP). It's generated by

```
var contentMD5 = haxe.crypto.Base64.encode(haxe.io.Bytes.ofString(haxe.crypto.Md5.encode(_data)));
```

with `_data` in my example being

```
<Delete><Object><Key>nathan/storage/72ENgrtnpA5VAoy7zEpzPRNEChN0TRGc</Key></Object><Object><Key>nathan/storage/7rlZZSJFvZ7AxUhQZsh4ufn9M2x8m1ae</Key></Object><Object><Key>nathan/storage/HN8NFlUnJiiGo7qlddvRrlGE6hPmWMnZ</Key></Object><Object><Key>nathan/storage/SFsZ8z63DswEVFJQJqmUwbenaWyfZ8zb</Key></Object><Object><Key>nathan/storage/YSYXXgYbSZixOKo27PL65ii6nCeiFesl</Key></Object></Delete>
```

My full request sent to AWS (for a multiple delete call as described here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/multiobjectdeleteapi.html), using AWS signature version 4 (bucket, signature, and credential shortened):

```
POST /?delete= HTTP/1.1
Host: mybucket.s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
Content-Length: 392
x-amz-content-sha256: 53da469cb6fc9d0701a1c6ff98d48edd361cd8a90d8a290a2dd224b2681bf7fb
x-amz-date: 20150923T195117Z
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=zzzzz/20150923/eu-central-1/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-md5;host;x-amz-date, Signature=xxxxx
Content-MD5: MDAzNDZmZjJiMGJkMDFkNzVjYzFiOGE4MzI5NTc0NGY=

<Delete><Object><Key>nathan/storage/72ENgrtnpA5VAoy7zEpzPRNEChN0TRGc</Key></Object><Object><Key>nathan/storage/7rlZZSJFvZ7AxUhQZsh4ufn9M2x8m1ae</Key></Object><Object><Key>nathan/storage/HN8NFlUnJiiGo7qlddvRrlGE6hPmWMnZ</Key></Object><Object><Key>nathan/storage/SFsZ8z63DswEVFJQJqmUwbenaWyfZ8zb</Key></Object><Object><Key>nathan/storage/YSYXXgYbSZixOKo27PL65ii6nCeiFesl</Key></Object></Delete>
```

The response is as follows (RequestId and HostId shortened)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>InvalidDigest</Code><Message>The Content-MD5 you specified was invalid.</Message><Content-MD5>MDAzNDZmZjJiMGJkMDFkNzVjYzFiOGE4MzI5NTc0NGY=</Content-MD5><RequestId>rrrrrr</RequestId><HostId>ccccccc</HostId></Error>
```

In my opinion, the generated MD5 is correct. I verified the value with other tools. Also, note that `x-amz-content-sha256` is based on the same `_data` and AWS accepted that header in my previous (non delete) calls.

What am I missing here? Why does my MD5 value differ from the one AWS generates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close.

Here's the problem:

An md5 hash is 16 bytes in binary representation, 32 characters in hexadecimal representation, and 24 characters (Including padding) in base64.

Yours is approximately twice as long.  You appear to be taking the 32 character hex md5, and base64-encoding *that*, resulting in a base64 string of about 44 characters, instead of just encoding the binary form.

Note that the length of the output, 44 vs 24 is not a factor of two in spite of my assertion that you are encoding 32 initial bytes instead of 16.  That's expected, because base64 output_bytes = ceil(input_bytes/3) * 4.

My expertise is with the S3 API -- not haxe, which I've never used -- so the above is almost certainly correct, but the following is wild speculation.

```
var contentMD5 = haxe.crypto.Base64.encode(haxe.crypto.Md5.make(_data));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael, very comprehensive. Your suggested Haxe code didn't work but it led me to the correct solution: `var contentMD5 = haxe.crypto.Base64.encode(haxe.crypto.Md5.make(haxe.io.Bytes.ofString(_data)));`

Answer (score 0):

Any one out there looking to do this in java can use this code

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
public class GenerateMD5 {
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    String s = "<CORSConfiguration> <CORSRule> <AllowedOrigin>http://www.example.com</AllowedOrigin> <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod> <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod> <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod> <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader> <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds> </CORSRule> <CORSRule> <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin> <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod> <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader> <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds> </CORSRule> </CORSConfiguration>";

        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md.update(s.getBytes());
        byte[] digest = md.digest();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        /*for (byte b : digest) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02x", b & 0xff));
        }*/
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
        StringBuffer sbi = new StringBuffer();
        byte [] bytes = Base64.encodeBase64(digest);
        String finalString = new String(bytes);
        System.out.println(finalString);
    }
}
```

The commented code is where most people get it wrong changing it to hex